# ASP.NET MVC3 WebGrid format: parameter

Tags: c#, lambda, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I am trying to use the new WebGrid in ASP.NET MVC3 and one of the columns I want to display set of link icons that performs various actions (Edit, View, Delete)...
For this purpose I have a HtmlHelper extensions that basically outputs following HTML:

```
<a href="" title=""><img alt="" src="" /></a>
```

The extension returns MvcHtmlString and it works fine when used in Razor views by itself..Eg:
@Html.ActionLinkIconForEditAction("Customer", 2)

The issue is I need to invoke this helper (once for each action) in WebGrid column while passing the ID of the object. The problem that I am stumped on is that compiler gives me an error saying that it cannot convert MvcHtmlString (or 'lambda expression' depending on invocation I try) to System.Func expected by the format...

So for example, this works:

```
grid.Column(header: "", format: @<text>@Html.ActionLinkIconForEditAction("Customer", 2)</text>)
```

But this does not:

```
grid.Column(header: "", format: (customer) => @<text>@Html.ActionLinkIconForEditAction("Customer", customer.Id)</text>)
grid.Column(header: "", format: (customer) => Html.ActionLinkIconForEditAction("Customer", customer.Id))
```

I get:

```
Error 4 Argument 3: cannot convert from 'lambda expression' to 'System.Func<dynamic,object>'
```

or for this call:

```
grid.Column(header: "", format: Html.ActionLinkIconForEditAction("Customer", customer.Id)),
```

I get:

```
Error 5 Argument 3: cannot convert from 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString' to 'System.Func<dynamic,object>'
```

What is weird I have other columns that ustilize lambdas, direct Model.Property accessors, and even output from String.Format("")...They all work fine...
I read all the docs on Func and [this thread as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213527/how-does-funct-tresult-work), and still can't quite figure it out :)

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Update: according to this post, there may be an issue with using dynamic objects in new WebGrid...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195440/mvc-3-texbox-in-webgrid-razor

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I got it :) ....
The issue appears to be in the way C# handles dynamic objects...Lots of users are having a blast with this...

The fix was as simple as casting a correct type on the parameter to my extension helper...
So this works:

```
grid.Column(header: "", format: @<text>@Html.ActionLinkIconForEditAction("Customer", (int)item.Id)
```

The other trick is to use "built" in "item" object and not provide your own..So, for example, this does not work:

```
grid.Column(header: "", format: (customer) =>  @<text>@Html.ActionLinkIconForEditAction("Customer", (int)customer.Id)
```

Lots of reading, tweaking, learning...
Hopefully, next version will have something a lot easier to use when you need to add content to columns that are not coming directly from the model...

Regards
Z...

Comment: Thanks, I came across this looking for info on formatting a column with my own custom html. the difference is that I'm using the default view engine and struggled to find an equivalent of the "@<text>@Html..." notation, so what I did was to create an MvcHtmlString: grid.Column("Field","Header", item => MvcHtmlString.Create(string.Format("<p class=\"CssClass\">{0}</p>", item.Field))) Thought I'd share. Is there a better way? please point me to it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("EditCustomer","Editcustomer", new {CustomerId=item.CustomerId}))
```

This will work ,and above one also work..
Here 1st "EditCustomer" is the text to be visible to users ,
second "EditCustomer" is the name of action you want it to redirect ,
and item is

Answer (score 1):

I had to create a `WebGrid` in C# code and had to display a specific column using hyperlink. None of the techniques mentioned above worked for me. So, I used `MvcHtmlString.create` and passed in the return value of `String.format` to it.

```
  format: (item) => MvcHtmlString.Create(string.Format((A HREF=\"/Inventory/EditInventory/{0}\"){1}(/A)", item.ID, item.Property)))
```

Replace the ( or ) inside the string with < or > respectively.