# Using System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, view, controller, webgrid

I'm trying to use a WebGrid to display data in my model and am having a huge number of issues.  My model contains among other things this:

```
public IEnumerable<Auction> Auctions { get; set; }
```

What I have done is:

```
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model.Auctions, rowsPerPage: Model.PagingInfo.ItemsPerPage, defaultSort: "Title", canPage: true, canSort: true)
        {SortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending};
    grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);
}
```

I want to display some text in the first column depending on the type of the auction in the current row, so I have written a method in the model:

```
public string GetAuctionType(Auction auction)
    {
        var type = string.Empty;
        if (auction is LubAuction)
        {
            type = "Lowest unique wins";
        }
        else if (auction is EsfAuction)
        {
            type = "Highest wins";
        }

        return type;
    }
```

Now, my view also contains:

```
@grid.GetHtml(
        columns: grid.Columns(
                grid.Column("OwnerReference", header: "Owner reference")

            )
        );
```

Question is how do I add a grid.Columns line in the above to display the text in GetAuctionType?

Also, the other issue is that there is no pager appearing and sorting does not work.

I would appreciate all help.

Thanks,

Sachin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would move GetAuctionType logic to a Partial Class so you can access it like a normal property on each object in your collection. You may also want to take a look at question [ASP.NET MVC3 WebGrid format: parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122691/asp-net-mvc3-webgrid-format-parameter) that is covering usage of WebGrid's column format syntax.

Regarding your other issues, do you see any errors in javascript console ?