# MVC Action link with dynamic parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I am using MVC and my requirement is that i need to build a action link with dynamic action route value.

for example.

In my model i have the `list<string>` so action link should be.

```
../ActionMethodName/ControllerName? Item[0]=model.item[0]&Item[1]=model.Item[1]...so on.
```

Any Suggestion is welcome.

Comment: So....what have you tried?

Comment: I am trying to create extension method..to generate custom action link. but now facing another issue and same issue is in this post...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057583/webgrid-cannot-convert-from-lambda-expression-to-system-funcdynamic-object

Comment: Note this action link need to use in web grid.

Answer (score 0):

Several ways.

1) You can pass as array and access it.

3) You can use foreach with razor syntex to generate this type of link.

Comment: I can't pass as array, i need to send in mentioned format (Item[0]=model.item[0]&Item[1]=model.Item[1]...so on)....2nd point for each...i am not sure how to use while declaring routevalue in action method..Please post some sample code..

Answer (score 0):

Initally , the parameter needs to be passed are hardcoded than OnClick of somthing , replace the queryString values .

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Test", "actionName", "ControllerName", new { foo = "foo1", name = "ABC" }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "TargetName" }, new { id = "Test" })
```

and

```
 $("#btnTest").click(function () {
      // Replace the hardcoded parameter value desired one ... :)  
      $("#Test").attr('href', $("#Test").attr('href').replace("foo1", "XXX"))     
    });
```

Note:- this solution i read from asp.net forums

[http://forums.asp.net/t/1841591.aspx?+pass+Javascript+value+parameter+with+Ajax+ActionLink](http://forums.asp.net/t/1841591.aspx?%20pass%20Javascript%20value%20parameter%20with%20Ajax%20ActionLink)